# Neo4J/Cypher: is it possibile to filter the length of a path in the where clause?

Tags: path, neo4j, cypher, where-clause

Let's suppose we have this simple pattern:

```
p=(a)-[r]-(b)
```

where nodes a and b have their own properties already set in the WHERE clause (e.g. a:Movie AND a.title = "The Matrix" AND b:Movie).
I'd like to add another condition in the WHERE clause like

```
LEGHT(p) =2 OR LENGTH(p)>6
```

(not the correct syntax, I know)

As far as I know, it is possibile to specify the length of a path in the MATCH clause with the syntax [r*min..max] but that doesn't cover the case I'm looking for.

Any help would be appreciated =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that does work in neo4j, exactly as you've specified.

Sample data:

```
create (a:Foo)-[:stuff]->(b:Foo)-[:stuff]->(c:Foo);
```

Then this query:

```
MATCH p=(x:Foo)-[:stuff*]->(y:Foo) 
WHERE length(p)>1 RETURN p;
```

Returns only the 2-step path from `a->b->c` and not either one-step path (`a->b` or `b->c`)

Comment: I've already tried that method with the simple movie db Neo4J offers. Although it only has a limited number of nodes/relationships, it got stuck at "Executing query...". I was looking for something more solid.

Comment: You should put hard constraints on your source and target nodes.  If you do this generally, like `MATCH (a)-[b]->(c)` then your query will have to match **every single possible path in the entire database**.  That number will be extremely high, and your query will take very long.

Comment: Yeah, that should work. The problem here is that putting hard constraints will be up to the user and I cannot foresee if it will be smart enough to do so =)

Comment: So basically your question is answered.  You can filter for paths the way you expected, but you have issues associated with making this query perform well.  You might consider using `shortestPath()` too

Comment: I suppose so...though it didn't go as I hoped =)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH p=(a)-[r*2..]-(b)
WHERE LENGTH(r) = 2 OR LENGTH(r) > 6
RETURN p
```

Note that with a large DB this query can take a very long time, or not finish, since the `MATCH` clause does not set an upper bound on the path length.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.
I'm creating a UI to build cypher queries and I put the "legth" properties of a path among the others (e.g. node label, relationship type, etc...). The user should have had the possibility of deciding whether a path length should be =,<,<=,>,>= a specified amount. I do now imagine I have to rethink that...